# Change keybindings in Blazblue Chrono Phantasma Extend without gamepad or numlock key

Tags: blazblue-chrono-phantasma-extend

I just got *BlazBlue: Chrono Phantasma Extend*. The problem is that the default button for OK/Cancel is the Numlock Key, which doesn’t exist on my Laptop. I can't enter settings to change the keybindings without Numlock.

**Is there any way to change key bindings without using a gamepad or the numlock key?**

Comment: Your laptop should have a "FN" key, which should give you access to a virtual keypad. The FN key works just like Shift.

Comment: i don't think so. my keyboard didn't numbers on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to press U instead of Enter in the title menu :v